# maven compilation fails with error static interface methods are not supported in -source 1.7

Tags: java, maven, java-8

maven is pointing to java 1.8, but maven command complains 
use -source 8 or higher to enable static interface methods

```
$mvn -version
```

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0
Apache Maven 3.1.0 (893ca28a1da9d5f51ac03827af98bb730128f9f2; 2013-06-27 19:15:32-0700)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.1.0
Java version: 1.8.0_101, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.101-3.b13.el6_8.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

```
 echo $JAVA_HOME
```

/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64
Can anyone help point out what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing an actual pom, but probably you should configure Maven compiler plugin to work with Java 8.

You can see an example of doing this here [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html).

The easiest way probably would be:

```
<project>
 [...]
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
 [...]
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think maven project run on lower version of jdk 8. please check the version, go to project properties>Project Facets> java 1.8 version is select or not... if not then select and apply and run again.

Answer (score 0):

completing the first answer

I got same problem after read
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

in pom.xml we need to set source and target of maven-compiler-plugin or the default is too low

```
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```